# Count the number of entries in two columns by one set of intervals with R

Tags: r, plot, graph, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two columns populated with numbers from similar distributions. I want to plot on a graph the density of each column in chosen intervals. I don't know how best to describe so I hope the code below shows my intentions.

My data is somewhat similar to this.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(A = rnorm(1000, 0 5), B = rnorm(1000, 10, 5)
```

So far the best method I can come up with includes a left join but its not an ideal method.

```
df$Cut_A <- cut(df$A, seq(-30, 30, 5)
df$Cut_B <- cut(df$B, seq(-30, 30, 5)

df_a <- df %>% group_by(Cut_A) %>% summarise(count_A = n())
df_b <- df %>% group_by(Cut_B) %>% summarise(count_B = n())

df2 <- left_join(df_a, df_b, by = c('Cut_A' = 'Cut_B'))
```

DF2 is missing counts from some of the intervals as they do not appear in the A column.

Any better methods or fixes to get the desired graph is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to discretize your variable and count frequencies manually, `ggplot::geom_histogram()` can do all of that under the hood:

```
data.frame(A = rnorm(1000, 0, 5), B = rnorm(1000, 10, 5)) %>% 
  # Gather the two variables into one column:
  gather %>% 
  # gather() created two columns: 'key' and 'value'
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = key)) +
  # Plot the frequency within each of your desired bins using the "breaks" argument:
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(-30, 30, 5))
```

[image]

#### Explanation

When you use gather (without naming any columns to exclude) it puts all of your variables in long format into one column called 'value'. In another column called 'key', the original variable names will be repeated for each row of data originally containing that variable. When you plot it, assigning the fill color to the variable will then create one histogram for each variable in 'key'. You can then use the breaks argument to set the bins to cut the variables as you would have using `cut`. It will do the same binning for each variable and compute frequencies separately because you set 'fill' to separate variables in 'key'.